# How to change my Basic github authentication to Token authentication requirements for Git operations using Pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I received an email from GitHub stating:

You recently used a password to access the repository at ....

Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.

Thanks,
The GitHub Team

Although I read there link, I still don't understand what I have to do. Can someone explain to me step by step through Pycharm, the changes I need to make in order to meet the new github conditions?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Github account and generate a new token: https://github.com/settings/tokens
You may need at least Repo and Gist scopes for Pycharm (this is what I just saw testing it).
Then copy the new token displayed. You won't be able to access it again !

In PyCharm, in Settings/Github, create a new user, and click on "Enter token" to provide a token instead of the usual username/password.

You should be done.

Comment: I think I needed to `-` delete my old credentials first. Then `+` | Log In with Token. Also crucial, this line buried in [JetBrains instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/github.html): "The token must have the `repo`, the `gist` and the `read:org` scopes enabled in your account permissions". Otherwise you get a very unhelpful red error message "Incorrect credentials. Insufficient scopes granted to token."